# Unable to get property "allShopifyProduct" from the data I get from graphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, shopify, gatsby

I was learning how to use the shopify plugin but for this page it can't access the data from my shopify.

For other pages, I use the similar code and it works fine just for this page I can't figure the error ><

Any mistakes that I made?

This is my graphql query

```
{
  "data": {
    "allShopifyProduct": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "Shopify__Product__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0LzIyMDEzNzg2MTk0NDY=",
          "images": [
            {
              "id": "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Qcm9kdWN0SW1hZ2UvNzU5MDg5NDAxMDQyMg==",
              "originalSrc": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0164/9121/6950/products/Forfacebooksquare.jpg?v=1562306206"
            }
          ],
          "title": "NJ Experience",
          "description": "An Owlnext-Intern",
          "handle": "nj-experience"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
//import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
//import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
//import {BrowserRouter,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
//import ProductListing from "../ProductListing";
import datas, {Bought} from '../components/data';
import { Link , navigate} from "gatsby";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';


const styles = {
    card : {
        height : 350
    }
}


class Cards extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
    };


    // Another method which I tried but not working right now too so i remain the code here

    // data = useStaticQuery(
    //     graphql`
    //     query {
    //         allShopifyProduct {
    //           nodes {
    //             id
    //             images {
    //               id
    //               originalSrc
    //             }
    //             title
    //             description
    //             handle
    //           }
    //         }
    //       }
    //     ` 
    //   );


    handleSomething= () =>{
        console.log('test')
        this.analyticsEvents();
        this.handlePushData();
    };

    analyticsEvents = () =>{
        console.log("ga");

       // ga('send', 'event' ,'Bought1', 'Bought2', 'Bought3');

    };

    //Checking
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(this.props.data.allShopifyProduct.nodes[0].handle);
      };


    handlePushData = () => {
        navigate(`/product/${this.props.data.allShopifyProduct.nodes[0].handle}/`);
        Bought.push({ImageLink: this.props.ImageLink, Title: this.props.Title , Price: this.props.Price});
    };

    render(){

        const { classes } = this.props;

        return(

            <Card className={classes.card}>
                <CardActionArea>

                    <CardMedia
                        style = {{objectFit: "contain"}}
                        component="img"
                        height="200"
                        image= {this.props.ImageLink}
                        /> 

                    <CardContent>

                    <Typography gutterBottom  component="h2"> 
                        {this.props.Title}
                    </Typography>

                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    {this.props.Price}
                    </Typography>

                    <Button size="small" variant="contained" style = {{marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: "#0ABAB5"}} 
                    onClick={this.handleSomething}>
                        ADD TO CART
                    </Button>

                </CardContent>

                </CardActionArea>
            </Card>


        )
    }
}


export const query = graphql`
query Query{
    allShopifyProduct {
      nodes {
        id
        images {
          id
          originalSrc
        }
        title
        description
        handle
      }
    }
  }
` 

export default withStyles(styles)(Cards);
```

It should be able to fetch the data

***Update***

This is my index.js which include the Card component

````
Thanks so much for helping out! This is the first page which include the cards component

Btw,do you mean that the data in graphQl have to pass in to the Cards component in this page? I thought the graphQL data could be import at any .js file as long as you call it in the .js file you want

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import Cards from '../components/Cards';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
//Assets
import datas from '../components/data';
import { graphql } from "gatsby"



export default class HomePage extends Component{


  render(){

      return(
        <>
          <SEO title="Home" />
          <Grid
              container
              spacing={8}
          >
              {datas.map(books =>(
                  <Grid key={books.Title} item xs={3}>    

                      <Cards history={this.props.history}  ImageLink={books.ImageLink} Title={books.Title} Price={books.Price} />
                  </Grid>
              ))}            
          </Grid>

        </>
      )


  }

}```
````

Comment: What does `console.log` prints in `componentDidMount` function?

Comment: It doesn't print anything and direct shows this error which is **TypeError: Unable to get property 'allShopifyProduct' of undefined or null reference**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `componentDidMount` you should check in [`componentDidUpdate`](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/postrender_with_componentdidupdate.html) like,

```
componentDidUpdate(){
   console.log(this.props.data.allShopifyProduct.nodes[0].handle);
};
```

As `componentDidMount` only executes when component is mounted, and your data may take time to come so it is possible that  `componentDidMount` will get execute before data comes in `this.props.data`. The best way to do this is in `componentDidUpdate` function.

**Update**

As you are using `Cards` component like this,

```
<Cards history={this.props.history}  ImageLink={books.ImageLink} Title={books.Title} Price={books.Price} />
```

You are passing `history` as props and not `data`, so you must use this,

```
componentDidUpdate(){
   console.log(this.props.history.allShopifyProduct.nodes[0].handle);
};
```

Comment: This is the same error after I apply your suggestion, Is there any error in the codes which making it is not fetching the data?                                                           
                                                                                                                       **TypeError: Unable to get property 'allShopifyProduct' of undefined or null reference**

Comment: handlePushData = () => {
> 77 |        navigate(`/product/${this.props.data.allShopifyProduct.nodes[0].handle}/`);
  78 |        Bought.push({ImageLink: this.props.ImageLink, Title: this.props.Title , Price: this.props.Price});
  79 |    };                                       **This is the error message at line 77**

Comment: Post your component where you are adding `Cards` component.

Comment: It is quite possible that you missed to pass your data as props to `Cards` component. Or `this.props.data` is empty.

Comment: Okk I ll post it at the answer section! Please check it out if you are free! Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: @NgJingXuan You are not passing `data` as props to your `Cards` component, instead you are passing `history` as props. You must use `history` to get data in `Cards` component, like my updated answer.

Comment: Ohh I have use your suggestion but it still output the same error which is ***TypeError: Unable to get property 'allShopifyProduct' of undefined or null reference***

Comment: `console.log(this.props)` render method and check if history object is available or not empty. If history object is available then check if it contains allShopifyProduct object.

Comment: When ```console.log(this.props.history)``` it is undefined , when ```console.log(this.props.history)``` it is error

Comment: It means you are not getting data in `this.props.history` in `Homepage` component itself. Make sure `this.props` has data. Check from where you are getting data, and how you are passing data.

Comment: Also make sure where you are including `Homepage` component you are passing `history` as props.

Comment: Ohh by the way, why I cant call the data from graphql on this the Card.js? Does it has to be passed down by the page which have its entry which is in index.js which contains my Homepage class component?

Comment: You need to pass data all the way down to child components, where you want to use that data.

Comment: In your case from `index.js` to `Homepage` and from `Homepage` to `Cards`.

Comment: Also make sure the name of props should get matched in child component.

Comment: Oh I see, but i followd the way he did in this starter-pack (https://github.com/AlexanderProd/gatsby-shopify-starter) and he did call the data at the child component

Comment: Isit because i using ```this.props.history``` so I'll need to pass down?

Comment: Yes you need to pass down history object.

Comment: Example you are referring is using `context` to pass data. Are you using `context`?

Comment: By the way, I found that the history pass down in the child component Cards is not useful for me as that is due to when I learn to use react-router,

But after I deleted it, the data still can't be call in the child component js file and I saw the starter-kit which I send above it able to use it.... Arghh hahhah quite frustrated on this ><

Comment: If you don't want to use data in child component simply don't pass data to child component.

Comment: Yes i want to use it but instead of passing it, I was figuring about declaring and calling it out in the child component js file ,  but it seems not working even I delete the history to be passed as a props and calling the data in the child component js file using ```this.props.data.allShopifyProduct```

Comment: If you don't want to pass data from every child and use directly in child component then you must use `context` as used in your referral link - https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html